# Dividing a single pin Arduino LED Matrix into sectors

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, arduino, led

I have an LED matrix, 16x16, made up of WS2812b LED strips, they are connected to an Arduino UNO using one Digital Pin. Obviously the indexes of the array go from 0-255 with LED # 0 being in the top right corner of the square, wired in a serpentine pattern. While experimenting with the layout I have been sending "image" or "designs" to my matrix using 256 item arrays running through a for loop, I am wanting to know if there is a way I can "divide" the matrix array into quarters, I'm thinking using another array to address the original, in order to more visually/manually assign a color to each LED, or if there is a way for a loop to cycle through a 256 item array in a serpentine pattern. I've added a link to a picture with the current index layout and the order that I would prefer to be able to items in.

Comment: And what is your question? But please read this first https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Where is the picture? (Please use the little [edit] link on the left below your question to enhance it. And please make sure that you get the syntax right to make the picture visible. You might like to take the [tour], too.)

Comment: You can organize your software and your data structures as you like, it's up to you. Just don't expect a ready-made solution for your specific task. You might need to use nested loops. If you encounter some programming problem, show us what you got so far by posting the source, and ask.